# Remove function alias in PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

Is there a way to remove function alias in PHP?

I can rename my function but it would be nice to use name `"fetch"`.

Problem:

[image]

Comment: phpDesigner7, just searched docs http://php.net/manual/en/aliases.php, fetch is nowhere to be found, my bad. "Fatal error: Call to undefined function fetch()"

Comment: almost all the ide has some kind of command/function syntax file, maybe is worth to take a look on that syntax file (and remove those you do no need)

Comment: Just looked, there is an XML file with all PHP functions, but there is no "fetch", doesn't matter, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

(Short of recompiling the PHP binary)

Comment: While you are there :) Same thing for renaming functions?

Comment: No, you can't rename functions. The core PHP language isn't malleable.

Comment: Runkit makes the core PHP language malleable as watery pudding. And we all know how much fun watery pudding can be.

Answer (score 1):

I just tested the following code and it appears to work for me, but perhaps it is because I don't have the mysqli library installed. I would test it because it might be more contextual than your IDE will have you believe. It seems to be a method for mysqli, but it might not be a global function.

```
<?php

function fetch(){
    echo 'Hello world!';
}

fetch();
```

Comment: Thank you, I also have tested it on server (after I posted question) it doesn't exist. It is IDE fault. I was annoyed by it every time I typed fetch()

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a function of the IDE than the actual language... Some IDEs may give you that ability... I don't even know if recompiling the PHP binary (as Alan Storm suggested) would help since sometimes the stuff is hardcoded into the IDE / use the PHP docs online

Comment: Yes, it is definitely in IDE somewhere. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness sake: Normally, no, this can not be done. However: this can be done using a PECL extension called "runkit".

Runkit is described as "For all those things you probably shouldn't have been doing anyway", and allows you to basically tear out the innards of PHP from within PHP itself. Replacing built-in functions, undefining constants, unloading classes - suddenly everything is possible. And you should really question what you are doing if you ever feel you need it - odds are what you are doing violates some principles that are there for very good reasons, you just don't know them yet. I've never found a situation where using Runkit was a genuinely Good Idea.

Oh, in order to remove built-in functions you'll specifically need to enable this capability in your php.ini

(have fun!)